# Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'oppazzgiftcode_app_OppazZ'@'localhost' for table 'productcode'

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

I am using two different databases and I have to fetch data from both databases with the user and product code, in productcode table, there is a foreign key sale_by when I join both of the tables I got the above error.

In my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=


DB_CONNECTION_SECONDARY=secondary
DB_HOST_SECONDARY=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECONDARY=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECONDARY=
DB_USERNAME_SECONDARY=
DB_PASSWORD_SECONDARY=
```

In mu config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'secondary' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_SECONDARY'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECONDARY', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECONDARY', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECONDARY', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECONDARY', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECONDARY', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_SECONDARY', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Here is my query

```
$response = DB::table('secondary.productcode')->select('name as customer_name', 'productcode', 'luckydrawcode', 'reward', 'activated_at', 'users.mobile_number')
            ->join('mysql.users', 'mysql.users.id', '=', 'secondary.productcode.sales_by')
            ->where('secondary.productcode.sales_by', auth('api')->id() ?? auth()->id())
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue first **I clear the logs** and then the issue was same after that I just **reassign all the privileges** of the database.
I hope this will help.
[image]